# Adding image in one struct updates another view

Tags: swift, swiftui

Running into an issue where I have two sections where a user can upload photos. The first being the profile picture where I implement a cache system like so:

```
class UrlImageModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var image: UIImage?
    @Published var urlString: String?
    var imageCache = CacheImageManager.getImageCache()
     @Published var newImageAdded = false
     @Published var pulledCacheImage: UIImage?
     init (urlString: String?) {
         self.urlString = urlString
         loadImage()
    
     }
  
    func loadImage() {
        guard let urlString = urlString else {
            return
        }
        if newImageAdded {
            print("new Image Added")
            loadImageFromURL()
        }
       else if loadImageFromCache() && newImageAdded {
            print("cache located") // AFTER INPUT LOADING, NO NEW IMAGE
            return
        }
        else{
            loadImageFromURL()
        }
    }

    func loadImageFromCache() -> Bool {
        guard let urlString = urlString else {
            print("urlString is nil")
            return false
        }
        
       // print("cache LOADING: \(imageCache)") // << after input input second outcome printed // 4th after refreshing NO NEW IMAGE
        
        guard let cacheImage = imageCache.getCache(forKey: urlString) else {
            print("cache not found for key: \(urlString)") // << 5th SHOWS NEW IMAGE!! OR INIATIES IT
            return false
        }
        
        image = cacheImage
        return true
    }

    private func loadImageFromURL (){
      
        guard let urlString = urlString else {
                 return
             }
        let url = URL(string: urlString)!
           let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with:url, completionHandler:
               getImageFromResponse(data: response: error: ))
           task.resume()
    }
    
    private func getImageFromResponse (data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?){
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
         
            guard error == nil else {
                print("error: \(error!)")
                return
            }
        }
        
        guard let data = data else {
            print("no data for image found")
            return
        }
        
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            guard let loadedImage = UIImage(data: data) else {
                return
            }
            self.imageCache.setCache(forKey: self.urlString!, image: loadedImage)
            self.image = loadedImage
        }
    }
}

class CacheImageManager {
    static let shared = CacheImageManager()
    private lazy var cache: NSCache<NSString, UIImage> = {
        let cache = NSCache<NSString, UIImage>()
        cache.countLimit = 100
        cache.totalCostLimit = 1024 * 1024 * 100
        return cache
    }()
    
    func getCache(forKey key: String) -> UIImage? {
        return cache.object(forKey: NSString(string: key))
    }
    
    func setCache(forKey key: String, image: UIImage) {
        cache.setObject(image, forKey: NSString(string: key))
    }
    
    func removeCache(forKey key: String) {
        cache.removeObject(forKey: NSString(string: key))
    }
}
extension CacheImageManager{
    private static var imageCache = CacheImageManager()
    static func getImageCache() -> CacheImageManager {
        imageCache
    }
}
```

I then have the second scenario where a user can upload an image below:

```
private func persistImageToStorage() {
            guard let uid = FirebaseManager.shared.auth.currentUser?.uid else { return }
            let ref = FirebaseManager.shared.storage.reference(withPath: uid)
        
            guard let imageData = self.inputImage?.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.5) else { return }
            ref.putData(imageData, metadata: nil) { metadata, err in
                if let err = err {
                   print("failed to push to storage \(err)")
                    return
                }

                ref.downloadURL { url, err in
                    if let err = err {
                        print("failed to fetch download link")
                        return
                    }

                   print("Image saved Successfully")
                    guard let url = url else { return }
                    
                    //save
                    image = url.absoluteString
                    ema.recipeImage = url.absoluteString
                   
                }
            }
        }
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            VStack{
                VStack{
                    WebImage(url: URL(string: image))
                        .placeholder(Image("defaultRecipeImage").resizable())
                        .resizable()
                        .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10.0))
                        .frame(width:320, height: 200)
                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                    }
                .padding(.top, 15)
                .onChange(of: inputImage, perform: { _ in
                    persistImageToStorage()
                })
               struct EditorImagePicker: UIViewControllerRepresentable{
    @Binding var imageForRecipe: UIImage?

    class Coordinator: NSObject, PHPickerViewControllerDelegate{
        var parent: EditorImagePicker

        init(_ parent: EditorImagePicker){
            self.parent = parent
            print("locator b")
        }

        func picker(_ picker: PHPickerViewController, didFinishPicking results: [PHPickerResult]) {
            picker.dismiss(animated: true)

            guard let provider = results.first?.itemProvider else { return }

            if provider.canLoadObject(ofClass: UIImage.self){
                provider.loadObject(ofClass: UIImage.self){image, _ in
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.parent.imageForRecipe = image as? UIImage
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> PHPickerViewController {
        //configures ios to just be able to select images
        var config = PHPickerConfiguration()
        config.filter = .images

        //the view of picker
        let picker = PHPickerViewController(configuration: config)
        picker.delegate = context.coordinator
        return picker
    }

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: PHPickerViewController, context: Context) {
        //leave empty for now
    }
}

 .sheet(isPresented: $showingImagePicker){
                    EditorImagePicker(imageForRecipe: $inputImage)
                }
```

The issue I'm encountering is when a user uploads an image for scenario 2, the profile picture then grabs that saved url and uses it as the new profile picture (and stores in cache). Is there something that is connecting the two that would be causing this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This mistake is:

```
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }
```

Because `self` is a value that is out of date when this struct is re-init. Fix like this:

```
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator()
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: PHPickerViewController, context: Context) {
       context.coordinator.imageForRecipeBinding = _imageForRecipe
    }
```

is there a reason you are not using SwiftUI built-in [`.photosPicker(isPresented:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/photospicker(ispresented:selection:matching:preferreditemencoding:)/)?

Comment: Can't thank you enough this was perfect. I ended up using .photosPicker (didn't even know honestly this was a feature) appreciate it!